# locally disable automatic ylabel rotation

Tags: pgfplots

Ordinate axis labels are rotated by default. This is not useful in case of short, single letter labels such as `$\phi$`.

How can I suppress rotation easily in a given plot? I couldn't find anything about it in section 4.8.3 (Labels).

With, e. g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$\phi$
]
\addplot{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

but I want

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can disable the rotation of the y label by adding `ylabel style={rotate=-90}` to the `axis` options.